# Cannot start ActionMode Callback in Android for ListView ItemLongClick

Tags: android, listview, android-actionmode

I do the following inside the onCreate

```
listTeams.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (mActionMode != null) {
                return false;
            }


            mActionMode = TeamActivity.this.startActionMode(TeamActivity.this);
            view.setSelected(true);

            return true;
        }
    });
```

But **TeamActivity.this** inside startActionMode is has red line and says that *android.view.ActionMode.Callback* cannot be applied in Activity

why? what I am missing here?

Comment: Are you implementing ActionMode.Callback interface in your activity ?

Comment: yes I did implements ActionMode.Callback

Comment: This error usually occurs when you have not implemented interface in your relevant activity. Make sure you have ActionMode.Callback implemented in your TeamActivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to access the method **startSupportActionMode** then it sounds like you have imported the wrong **ActionMode.Callback** class.

**android.view.ActionMode** - what you need to import.
**android.support.v7.view.ActionMode** - what you have imported.

Please check your imports at the top of the class.

Answer (score 2):

I know its too late for answer but non of the given answers was working for me,
Below answer may help some one.

Instead of method `startSupportActionMode()`, u can use `startActionMode()`.

Answer (score 0):

**startSupportActionMode** method is working with context TeamActivity.this but why?